# Warnings while using Docx4j with Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, docx4j

I wanted to create xlsx files using docx4j. I have a spring-mvc (4.x) application where i wrote the service. And it works as desired.

However, i see the following warning in the logs which i want to get rid of.

```
org.xlsx4j.jaxb.Context - org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties not found via classloader.
```

Docx4j has been pulled via pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To integrate docx4j, that is all i have done. I have not injected any beans (as Spring dependency). What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a docx4j.properties file to your class path.

You can find a [sample properties file on GitHub](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/_resources/docx4j.properties).